# deconstructor for custom vector class

Tags: c++

double free or corruption (fasttop) error.

I am working to build the vector class from scratch and am confused with the deconstructor.

the class is:

```
template <class T>
class Vector
{
public:
   typedef T * iterator; //pointer to type T

   Vector();                              
   ~Vector();                       

   void reserve(unsigned int capacity); 
   void resize(unsigned int size);      

private:
   unsigned int my_size;
   unsigned int my_capacity;
   T * buffer;
};

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector()
{
my_size = 0;
my_capacity = 0;
buffer = 0;
}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector(){
    delete [] buffer;
    my_size = my_capacity = 0;
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::reserve(unsigned int new_capacity){
    int * new_buffer = new T[new_capacity];
    for(int i=0; i<my_size;i++){
        new_buffer[i] = buffer[i];
    }
    my_size += new_capacity;
    my_capacity += new_capacity;
    buffer = new_buffer;
    delete new_buffer;
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::resize(unsigned int new_size){
   //if new_size < size, change size.
   if(new_size < size) 
   {
       size = new_size;
   } else {
       if(new_size > my_capacity){ //increase capacity for larget size
           while(my_capacity < new_size){
               reserve(my_capacity+5);
           }
       }
       for(int i = my_size; i < new_size; i++){
           buffer[i] = T();
       }
       my_size = new_size;
   }
}
```

Calling code:

```
int main()
{  
   Vector<int> v;
   v.reserve(2);
   assert(v.capacity() == 2);
   cout << "SUCCESSFUL!!!\n"; 
}
```

I am getting the successful output but it is when the deconstructor is called that I am getting the error I believe.

Comment: We need more code that this to determine the problem. Show us the class and show us how you're using the class please.

Comment: Better yet, show a completely complete code sample (including a main function) which compiles and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I am doing this in order to learn. Didn't want to post too much of the code in case the error was not in the deconstructor then I would need to continue looking.

Comment: `delete new_buffer;` should be `delete[] new_buffer;`

Comment: I don't see anything here that should cause a stack corruption. Are you sure this is all the relevant code?

Comment: What actually the reserve function do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reserve function is not correct for a number of reasons.  Instead, move the last line of that function before the `buffer = new_buffer`, and change it to `delete [] buffer`.  You need to delete what used to be in the vector before you assign to it the new data.  The way it is written, you are assigning a new buffer (losing track of the old buffer), then deleting all of the data from the new buffer.  So, when the deconstructor hits, you are deleting a pointer to nothing.